# Simplest way to run spray.io spray-can on Heroku

Tags: scala, heroku, sbt, akka, spray

I'm new in Scala and SBT. I want to run simple hello-world http server on Heroku with Spray and Akka. Spray-can's documentation at http://spray.io/documentation/spray-can/examples/ tells that simple example I can run this way:

```
git clone git://github.com/spray/spray.git
cd spray
sbt "project simple-http-server" run
```

It works, but it depends on akka.io.IO which is in spray-can source code and not merged to final Akka yet (`2.2-SNAPSHOT`) - http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/io.html.

1. Can I use akka.io.IO from Akka `2.2-SNAPSHOT` with my SBT? How?
2. Can I use akka.io.IO from Spray 1.1-M8-SNAPSHOT with my SBT? How?
3. Is there another simple way to run hello-world spray-can?

EDIT:

Ad. 1., 2.: akka.io.IO is in Akka `2.2-M3`

But example from spray-can source code still doesn't work because of lack of `spray.can.Http` in Spray `1.1-M7`. Any Idea how can I fix this?

```
package spray.examples

import akka.actor.{ActorSystem, Props}
import akka.io.IO
import spray.can.Http

object Main extends App {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem()

  // the handler actor replies to incoming HttpRequests
  val handler = system.actorOf(Props[DemoService], name = "handler")

  IO(Http) ! Http.Bind(handler, interface = "localhost", port = 8080)
}
```

Comment: The snapshot of Spray 1.1-M8 still only depends on Akka 2.1. Therefore, the IO module was backported from akka and is contained in spray for now so there is no dependency on Akka 2.2 yet. It's not clear to me what your problem actually is or what doesn't work. (Maybe let's take it over to the mailing list)

Comment: Maybe simply checkout the 1.1-M7 tag (https://github.com/spray/spray/tree/v1.1-M7, `git checkout v1.1-M7`) and run the examples from there. Should work without problems.

Comment: @adamw Thanks! Example from `tag 1.1-M7` without `akka.io.IO` works perfect.